# Oracle regular expression catching specific character

Tags: regex, oracle

here is what I am trying to do for more understanding i just wanna find away to get the substring and put it into variable

```
DECLARE
   v_file_type      thufitab.file_type%TYPE;
   v_filename       thufitab.filename%TYPE;
   v_status         thufitab.status%TYPE;
   V_seq_FILENAME   NUMBER (4);

   CURSOR List_FILENAME_cur
   IS
      SELECT FILENAME
        FROM thufitab
       WHERE status = 2 AND ROWNUM <= 100;
BEGIN
   FOR List_FILENAME_rec IN List_FILENAME_cur
   LOOP
      SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (FILENAME, '([1-9][0-9]{0,3})')
        INTO V_seq_FILENAME
        FROM thufitab;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (V_seq_FILENAME);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is - do you have any problems with your regex? Are there certain input values where it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I just wanna someone to check if the regular i wrote is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand well, but, is this ok for you?

```
'CDR-([1-9][0-9]{0,3})_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4}_UK1\.FCDR'
     ^_______________^
          group 1
```

Comment: okay nice is there is away to put the SEQ part into variable??

Comment: @user3304876: Sorry, I don't get you. What do you mean with `put the SEQ part into variable`?

Comment: from this format abc-SEQ_YY_MM_DD_HH24MI_UNIT_NAME.FCDR I want to get out the seq par and put it into variable

Comment: @user3304876: OK, just group the parts you want by enclosed them within parenthesis. See my edit. Refer to Oracle's documentation for how to retrieve groups.

Comment: @user3304876: Sorry, I don't know. As I said: Refer to Oracle's documentation for how to retrieve groups.

Comment: here is what I am trying to do for more understanding

    declare 
    v_file_type thufitab.file_type%type;
    v_filename thufitab.filename%type;
    v_status thufitab.status%type;
    V_seq_FILENAME number(4);  
    cursor List_FILENAME_cur is 
    select FILENAME 
    from thufitab 
    where status=2
    and rownum<=100;    
    begin
    for List_FILENAME_rec in List_FILENAME_cur
    loop
    select regexp_substr (FILENAME,'([1-9][0-9]{0,3})') into V_seq_FILENAME from thufitab;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_seq_FILENAME);
    end loop; 
    end;

Comment: @user3304876 Please update question text with this information.